# How to loop over multiple sub-folders and rename files based on a specific XML tag?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to rename or replace (whichever is easier) filenames in sub-folders based on a specific XML tag. Each sub-folder has 1 pdf and 1 XML file. The  current file names all have the wrong ID# and I want to replace that ID# with the correct ID located in the corresponding XML file. Is this possible?

```
Folder A(Parent folder)

    Folder B(Sub folder)
       1.pdf
       2.xml

    Folder B2(Sub folder)
       1.pdf
       2.xml

    Folder B3(Sub folder)
       1.pdf
       2.xml
```

Currently I able to loop through all the sub folders in the directory and print out the file names. I also have code that allows me to print out all the ID tags, but only if all the XML files are in 1 sub-folder. This doesn't help much because I have 1 XML file in each sub-folder.

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

for dir, sub, filenames in os.walk(path):
    print(dir)
    sub = [n for n in sub]
    contents = sub + filenames
    sub.sort()
    for f in contents:
        print(f)
        if f.endswith(".xml"):
            fullname = os.path.join(path, f)
            tree = ET.parse(fullname)
            root = tree.getroot()
            for ear in root.iter("EAR"):
                sec = ear.text  # gives me the full section #
                # print(sec[4:11] + " THese are the section numbers")

                new_fn = sec[4:11]
                # print(re.sub(",", "", new_fn))
                print(re.sub("[^\d\-]", "", new_fn))
```

From `if f.endswith` on, the code works if I have all the XML files in a single folder. In this current code it won't work looping through all my sub folders. I get an error saying `No such file or directory`.

**Note:** `"EAR"` is the tag I am looking for.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a (small) example `.xml` file folks could use for reproducing the problem and testing their solution (an [mcve]).

Comment: Thanks I solved my original question now. I got it to rename all my XML files.

Answer (score 0):

So i got it to work. Here's how I did it.

```
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            curr_fld = os.path.basename(root)
            old_name = os.path.join(path,curr_fld,file)

            # print(file)

            if file.endswith(".xml"):
                file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
                print(file_name)
                xmldoc = minidom.parse(os.path.join(root, file))
                try: 
                    item_id = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("EAR")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
                except IndexError:
                    print("skipped")


                try:
                    cfr, year, title, sec_num, txt_replace = file_name.split("-")

                except ValueError:
                    print("someone did it wrong.")

                item_id = re.sub("[^\d\-]", "", item_id)
                # print(item_id)



                new_name = "{}-{}-{}-{}{}".format(cfr, year, title, item_id, file_ext)
                new_name2 = os.path.join(path,curr_fld,new_name)

                # print(new_name)
                try:
                    os.rename(old_name,new_name2)

                except WindowsError:
                     continue
                     print("Didn't work!")
```